# Number as Argument for Command

Tags: macros, counters

I have defined the following:

```
\newcounter{testCounter}
\newcommand{\testCommand}[1]{
                             \setcounter{testCounter}{#1}
                             Your number is \ref{testCounter}!
                             }
```

Now I want to call this command in the document:

```
\begin{document}
\testCommand{12}
\end{document}
```

I was hoping for this to give me:

> Your number is 12!

However, I get the Error ,

> "There were undefined references."

Can someone explain to me why this wont work? It seems pretty straighforward... I am using the following packages also:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{nameref}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, but you're using the wrong way. `\ref{testcounter}` is trying to use a label named `testcounter` which does not exist.

Comment: Did you compiled twice?

Comment: I see, but I thought you reference a counter the same way, no?

Comment: AFAIK you need to use `\refstepcounter` to get a referencible counter. Maybe try to set, add -1 and then use refstep.

Comment: Warning does not go away after multiple compiles, and doesn#t yield the desired output

Comment: \ref{xyz} needs a \label{xyz} somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that this is about `\ref` at all... If the counter value should be printed, just use `\thetestCounter`

Comment: By the way: your `\testcommand` will generate spurious spaces

Comment: This looks like an XY question; what's the purpose of using a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print the number that is stored in a counter: Use `\thetestCounter` or `\arabic{testCounter}`

Any counter defined with `\newcounter` gets an associated macro `\theX`, which defaults to `\arabic{X}`, i.e. `\newcounter{foo}` defines `\thefoo`, printing the counter value with arabic figures.

If a reference should be used, another approach is needed, see `\otherCommand`, where the counter is set to a value reduced by one, then `\refstepcounter` is applied, immediately use a `\label` to 'freeze` the counter reference value.

This is written to the `.aux` file and can be loaded in the 2nd run and referred to right from the start!

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\myconstant}{4}

\newcounter{testCounter}
\newcommand{\testCommand}[1]{%
  \setcounter{testCounter}{#1}%
  Your number is: \thetestCounter%
}

\newcommand{\otherCommand}[1]{%
  %Does not need calc package
  \setcounter{testCounter}{\numexpr#1-1}%
  \refstepcounter{testCounter}%
}

\begin{document}
Later on, you will set the counter to \ref{somelabel}

\testCommand{12}

\testCommand{\numexpr12*\myconstant}

\otherCommand{1001}\label{somelabel} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the \arabic{...} was what I needed. But say I now needed to multiply this counter by, say, 3. How could I achieve that?

Comment: @DouglasJamesBock: That's another question. Do you want to multiple the counter value or its printed value?

Comment: I understand it's a different question. I was hoping that once I fix the problem in the question this would resolve, too. It didn't... I want to multiply the counter value by some constant.

Comment: `\testCommand{\numexpr 12*3}`, for example. `\numexpr` evaluates the calculation

Comment: @DouglasJamesBock: You can perform calculations on arguments using [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp). See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408561/5764).

Answer (score 1):

`\ref`erences work with `\label`s, so in order to use any `\ref`, you must have an accompanying `\label` somewhere. Moreover, `\label` grabs only specific kinds of referencable objects (yes, mostly counters, but those that have been "adjusted in a specific way"; see [Understanding how references and labels work](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)).

In your example, it is simpler to use

```
\newcommand{\testCommand}[1]{%
  Your number is #1!%
}
```

without a `\ref`. If you want to perform calculations on your number, you can use a package for this. Perhaps something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\testCommand}[1]{%
  Your number is \fpeval{#1}!%
}

\begin{document}

\testCommand{12}

\testCommand{12 * 3}

\testCommand{12 / 4}

\end{document}
```